# git clone then force divergence

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm trying to make a permanent fork of a repository to make it a module of the top level repository. Essentially, I want to clone my original repository, then break history so that pull/push between the new repository and the old one will not be allowed accidentally. [Github has an explanation for subdirectories](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) as do several Stackoverflow questions, but I would like to do the same for a whole repository.

Comment: Maybe just `git remote remove origin` in your clone?

Answer (score 0):

Add a different commit to `master` in each repository. That way only a force-push or an explicit merge can cause the histories to be recombined.

Comment: Just to add to the idea, you could create empty commits using `git commit -m "dummy commit" --allow-empty` on each of the master. Since the time, parent commit will always vary, each emptry commit would have a different SHA as well.

Comment: This seemed to have the problem where a pull from the wrong repository went through with no problems. If I were to pull from an unrelated repository I believe I'd see errors. However, I may be mistaken regarding the process I followed.

Comment: You'll want the two divergent changes to be on the same line of the file so that they conflict if someone tries to merge from the other repo.